# Rails 4 Modal Window (Pop Up Window) : How to Prevent from getting close on selecting a drop down Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have partial to enable a modal(pop up window) in my rails 4 app with a drop down list to select from it. The problem I am facing is that if I click on the drop down list and select an option it automatically closes, but I need the value to be remain there, still I click on the Close button or Save button.

My Modal Code is given bellow: _doctorselect.html.erb

```
 <div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

<h4>Add Referral to Doctors </h4>
</div>
  <div class="modal-body">

        <!-- Single button -->
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Please Assign Referral <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <!-- <li>Please Assign Referral</a></li> -->
              <% @practices.each do |practice| %>
                <!-- <li><a href="customers?practitionerid=<%= practice.user_id %>&type=<%= @type %> "><b>Dr.<%= practice.firstname %></b></a></li> -->
                <li><a href=""><b>Dr.<%= practice.firstname %></b></a></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>

    </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
  </div>
```

And the Js file is: doctorlist.js.erb

```
$("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'doctorselect') %>");
$("#modal-window").modal()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the bellow code with some modifications in my view code and .js file worked for me:

**_doctorselect.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag (assignreffaral_practices_path), id: "myform", method: 'get', remote: true  do |f| %>
<div class="modal-dialog ">
  <div class="modal-content modal-md">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h4 class=" glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> Add/Edit/Remove Referral to: Dr.<%= @Practitioner_name %></h4>
    </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="btn-group">
                  <table class="table ld-margin-top-20">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>                          
                        <td>
                            <!-- Single button -->
                            <%= collection_select(:customer, :id, @practices, :id, :full_name, {:prompt => 'Remove Referral' }, :class =>"form-control") %>
                        </td>

                        <td>

                          <button type="submit" onclick="window.location = '/practices'" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>

                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" id="doctor" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
              </div>
        </div>  
     </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**doctorselect.js.erb**

```
$("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'doctorselect') %>");
$("#modal-window").modal()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably associated with "clicking outside the modal window".

See Bootstrap [documentation for modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options):

> **backdrop** Includes a modal-backdrop element. Alternatively, specify `static` for a backdrop which doesn't close the modal on click.

So you should open your modal like this:

```
$("#modal-window").modal({ backdrop: 'static' })
```

or specify it in `data-backdrop` attribute of a button/link which launches this dialog. Now your modal should not close by clicking outside of the window.

Comment: my problem is that clicking on drop down list items, not while clicking outside window.

Comment: Didn't `{ backdrop: 'static' }` work for you? I think they should be related.

Comment: Did you try getting rid of the link within the drop down items? Currently you have an `a` tag with `href=""` inside each list item of the drop down. This could be causing the browser to try and navigate away every time you click on an item. Just a guess.